# Drawing a line with a gradient color

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, line, gradient

Is it possible to draw a line using a graduated colour?

I want to be able to draw a straight or a curved line (if possible) where at one end of the line is Blue and the other end is Red.

Further There might be a need to have more than one gradient per-line e.g the colour going from Blue -> Green -> Red. I am thinking that this might just consist of multiple gradient lines drawn together.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Graphics graphicsObject = e.Graphics;

    using (Brush aGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(50, 0), Color.Blue, Color.Red))
    {
        using (Pen aGradientPen = new Pen(aGradientBrush))
        {
            graphicsObject.DrawLine(aGradientPen, new Point(0, 10), new Point(100, 10));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, he doesn't need to in this case. Dispose() method will be called automatically after OnPaint method.

Comment: He should, on the paint Pen and Brush. Better yet, keep them alive as members and don't create new ones on each paint.

Comment: thanks guys. I hastily put the snippet together, which is my bad. Have fixed up.

Answer (score 5):

you will need to use `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush` instead of `System.Drawing.SolidBrush`

example:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(...
```