# How do I find a color that is between two other colors?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, algorithm

I am assigning each color a numeric value. For example:

```
Color.red: 12 
Color.Blue: 6
```

I need to find a color between two colors (for example, red and blue). But how? I have tried this,

```
(Color.red+color.blue)/2=> (12 + 6)/2 = 9
```

9 corresponds to Color.yellow

Comment: What's a color gap, and what do pixels have to do with colors?

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to build a linear gradient given a list of colors and the points within the gradient it should be each specific color?

Comment: i change and add new version of question

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576861/c-drawing-a-line-with-a-gradient-colour

Comment: @yx - It doesn't appear to be related as the other question is making use of the LinearGradientBrush to do the calculations for you where as this question appears to be asking how to do the calculations yourself. Plus, they don't appear to be drawing a line.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use the RGB values of the colour and interpolate between those. Using a single value isn't going to give you the discrimination you need.

The answer that yx quotes [Drawing a line with a gradient color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576861/c-drawing-a-line-with-a-gradient-colour) looks like a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

This problem requires you to split the alpha, red, green, and blue componenets of each colour, find the average of each, and create a new color:

```
    Color first = Color.Red;
    Color second = Color.Blue;


    byte r = (byte)((first.R + second.R) / (byte)2);
    byte g = (byte)((first.G + second.G) / (byte)2);
    byte b = (byte)((first.B + second.B) / (byte)2);
    byte a = (byte)((first.A + second.A) / (byte)2);

    Color mix = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
```